# Why sacrifice Pegasus?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

**Spoiler Alert:** Season 3, Episode 4, Exodus (Part 2)

Lee Adama defies Admiral Adama's orders and uses the Battlestar Pegasus to rescue Galactica from certain destruction. Galactica and Pegasus are under fire from four Basestars.

What was the reasoning behind sacrificing Pegasus (as opposed to sacrificing Galactica)? Galactica is a significantly older Battlestar and clearly inferior in technical capability to Pegasus. From the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlestar_Pegasus#Technical_information):

> As a Mercury class Battlestar, Pegasus is substantially newer, larger and more powerful than Galactica. It is nearly twice the size, but only carries around half the crew due to greater automation.
>
> Pegasus has vastly superior weapons, flight decks, and armor compared to Galactica. Its forward weapons battery can devastate a Cylon basestar with a single salvo. It is armed with large anti ship KEWs, anti fighter/missile batteries and nuclear weapons. It has much larger flight decks than Galactica, two on each side of the ship for a combined total of four flight decks. Pegasus had four fully operational squadrons of Vipers at the time it encountered Galactica, and automation systems that allowed the production of new Vipers to help replace Galactica's losses. Unlike Galactica, Pegasus had flight simulators on board to facilitate the training of new pilots.

Pegasus' raptors could have been used to evacuate the crew aboard Galactica instead. Why not sacrifice Galactica instead? (besides the fact it's the eponym of the series)

Comment: Cause lee is a moron?

Comment: The higher technology was known by the cylons, and compromised by them.  With a little lead-time the pegasus is a paper-weight.  While it is older, and more person-intensive, the Galactica is also resistant to the hacks that paralyzed the fleet while the colonies were initially crushed.

Comment: @EngrStudent I didn't think of that. Great point! But, as I understand, if the computers weren't networked, the battlestar would be safe from Cylon hacks.

Comment: I hated that part. Yeah, the show was about the Galactica but still.

Comment: Did it get destroyed. I remember in the original series Pegasus's fate was very much ambiguous.

Comment: In the new series it's pretty clear, the ship-wide explosions are on-screen and those on board have to evacuate.

Comment: @JeremyFrench it was destroyed and took 2 or 3 Basestars with it

Comment: @petersaber it is left fighting and not seen destroyed http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Pegasus_(TOS)

Comment: @JeremyFrench, that article explicitly refers to The Original Series (TOS)

Comment: @JeremyFrench I thought you were asking about the 2004 series ("I remember in the original series (...)", so you obviously know what happened in TOS), and my comment was about the fate of the Pegasus in the reimagined series, where the Pegasus destroyed/critically damaged a Basestar with the opening salvo, rammed to death another, and the debris (flight pod) crashed another Basestar and numerous Raiders.

Comment: I'm somewhat fascinated that no-one seems to have been able to contrive even a speculative answer to this question. It seems that fandom is in surprising agreement that it would have made more sense to sacrifice _Galactica_, if either had to be.

Comment: IIRC, Pegasus' raptors ended up helping in support the evacuation of New Caprica survivors, so they had their hands full with evacuees.  Also, there were food stores on Galactica, so while human lives always come first, running low on food was a very real issue to them.  One they needed to keep on top of, and even had at least few episodes dedicated to that.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

On the surface of it, there isn't a very rational in-universe reason to sacrifice *Pegasus* rather than *Galactica*. With the software vulnerability that began the entire series patched, one cannot even make a good argument that *Galactica*'s relatively primitive, un-networked systems are preferable in the running fight against the Cylons.

We are therefore left to consider less-than-rational in-universe possibilities (after all, human beings do not always make rational tactical decisions); and several out-of-universe ones.

In-universe, Lee Adama clearly felt a need to redeem himself a bit, both from his desultory behaviour after the colonization of New Caprica, and from his insistence on not joining in the rescue effort that he did, in the end, join in. This could have led him to make a spur of the moment, "I'll show them!" sort of decision with his ship that, while not really very sensible, was in character for Apollo.

The truth is that Apollo was probably not qualified, objectively, to command a Battlestar. He had no experience in large-vessel operations, let alone command, and had probably not received much training in a formal sense, either. He received the posting through a combination of attrition and nepotism that everyone accepted at the time because there weren't a lot of good alternatives. However, his receiving that command was more or less the equivalent of taking a Naval Aviator and putting him in command of the USS *Nimitz*, without any additional training or time as a ship-side officer, and expecting him to know what he was doing.

In this case, Apollo did with his Battlestar what we've seen several times he'd been willing to do with a Viper -- put himself directly in the line of fire to protect others -- without thinking through the questions of whether Galactica would have served exactly as well and made more sense to sacrifice.

So much for in-universe speculation. Out of universe, there were two reasons that make a certain sense:

- The show is, after all, *Battlestar Galactica*. It probably wouldn't have confused the audience all that much if suddenly the namesake ship were no longer around -- by that point, most people watching the series were in it for the long haul, not tuning in randomly. But it still might have just felt wrong to the showrunners.
- The entire *Pegasus* arc is inspired by a similar, if shorter arc in the Original Series, which ultimately led to *Pegasus* being sacrificed so that *Galactica* and the fleet could escape. In that case, *Pegasus* went missing, and could conceivably have turned up intact later if the series had not been cancelled, but the basic point is that the source material also made *Pegasus* the sacrifice. In retrospect, this was not necessarily a brilliant idea in the Original Series, either, as Commander Cain's military experience was invaluable, even if he did disagree a lot with Adama, and he disappeared along with his ship. So there, too, it seems to have been an emotional decision by the commanding officer (in the original series, Cain) to err on the side of bravura without really thinking through the strategic repercussions.

In the end, the modern *Battlestar Galactica* series can be seen as one long parable of how humans and humanity often make terrible decisions and then have to live with them. In that context, the sacrifice of *Pegasus*, while not a strategically brilliant move, at least fits the theme.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it made me realise that it is indeed very fitting with Lee's impulsive not-too-rational behaviour. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help! I just started rewatching the series and was reminded in particular of what an emotional and psychological mess Apollo really is, and thus realized I had an answer that was at least somewhat more satisfying than some of the comments.

Comment: I would add a couple of things to this - First it's more like an F-18 pilot then an F-16 pilot, and in fact there used to be a statue in the US Naval Code that required Aircraft Carrier Captains to previously have been Naval Aviators. Secondly, it's highly likely that because of the additional automation on the Pegasus, the Galactica was simply not able to be sacrificed in a way that would ensure the survival of a majority of it's crew as the Pegasus was. And we know also that the dwindling population of humanity is a concern by this point.

Comment: @Mark That's a good point about F18 vs F16 and the fact that Carrier COs are required  to have been aviators...but presumably they also go through some fairly rigorous training, and time as a ship-side officer on their way up to CO. Apollo pretty much got none of this.

Comment: @Mark I've tweaked the answer a bit to reflect the point more accurately based on your comment.

Comment: There's another reason - Galactica and her experienced crew, especially Adama, are a symbol that unites the fleet. Pegasus was a powerful ship, but only a ship that tagged along, while Galactica is the backbone the entire human race has been supported by. Without Admiral Adama's leadership and Galactica to rally around, the fleet could potentially break up and/or fall into despair, dooming the human race. And it's not a secret that humanity is very symbol-minded (pun intended)

Comment: We have to think of this from a background standpoint too: Pegasus was a seemingly cursed ship with a VERY DARK background. Countless atrocities had been committed by her commanding officers, she couldn't even keep a commanding officer in charge for very long before they were killed either by a Cylon or by a coup de' tat. She was a dark ship, and I believe the writers wanted to show that the ship essentially "redeemed" itself and its dark past by its remaining personnel (and Lee) making the ultimate sacrifice to help the Galactica and other civies get away. It's a classic 'redemption' trope.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan I like that take. I hadn't thought of it because I am not myself a very superstitious person, but it fits this scenario from a lot of different angles.

Comment: It's interesting that the writers decided to use the "redemption" trope with that ship because in TOS of BSG, (SPOLIER ALERT if you haven't seen it yet, stop reading!) Pegasus isn't a dark ship but has a stubborn commander who loves to make war, and ends up mysteriously disapearing at the end of a battle with the Cylons. They make no more mention of what happens to the ship. Its just............gone. In the re-made series, they decided to actually explain "Peggy's" demise.

Answer (score 4):

I recently binge watch BSG and I think I understand why the Pegasus was sacrificed...

First off, once it entered the battlefield, it seems the Cylons turned their full attention on the Pegasus, which allowed the Galactica to recover all it vipers and jump out. The Pegasus entered the battle without any vipers and was obviously a more tempting target for the Cylons. I would hope(since Apollo did leave all his viper behind to protect the fleet) he also removed as much as he could from the Pegasus in terms of equipment and other supplies.

Second, even though the Pegasus was bigger, it did not mean it had to means to provide a lot of living space since it was fully automated.  Since the Pegasus was new and automated, it was still vulnerable to Cylon hacks.  It is safer to go with something less technologically advanced, and as old as the Galactica to ensure it was fully protected from Cylon technology.

Lastly, the show was called `Battlestar Galactica`, in which the ship itself is the stage for all the human drama and it needed to remain apart of the story till the very end.  It also served as the protector of humanity and the Pegasus was just a reminder of humanity's arrogance.

Comment: also Galactica was more or less fully manned. Pegasus probably only flew in with a minimal crew that could likely fully evacuate. Sure, had Appollo not first objected to the plan, they could have spared Pegasus instead or even made it out with both ships. Then again, I found this back and forth only human. Adama is clever, but he doesn't know everything and it was a risky plan so it's understandable he got convinced to "play it safe" by leaving one Battlestar with the remaining fleet.

Comment: Furthermore, Galactica had its starboard side converted into living quarters.  Vipers and raptor cannot launch from that side due to that (they're housed and launched via port side).  If they wanted to replicate those living quarters on Pegasus, there's no telling how much work, and how much functionality would've been removed from her.

Answer (score 2):

It was military necessity.  Lee left the Pegasus vipers to protect the fleet, so he jumped to New Caprica without any, leaving him with only a few realistic scenarios:

1. Galactica had it mostly under control, so Pegasus could blast a basestar and give support, then jump out.  Would work if two or at most three basestars were present
2. Galactica was already lost but the battle continued, so Pegasus could take the remaining vipers and save what it could of the colonists.  Again, two or three basestars at the most.
3. The battle was already over and lost, so jump in and jump back to the remaining fleet and continue on.
4. The scenario that actually happened.  With four basestars it was probably the best possible outcome.

Comment: You might want to include some ways in which losing the better of the two warships would be considered the 'best possible outcome'

Answer (score 1):

I personally believe from a tactical standpoint the *Pegasus* was the only real option to sacrifice. It was bigger, stronger and able to obliterate and tank all the basestars in a fairly quick succession; a feat the *Galactica* would not have been able to do even in its prime.

As soon as the *Pegasus* arrived, the Cylons knew its capabilities and immediately focused fire. In addition, even though it was larger (as already mentioned), most of the *Pegasus* was automated and had smaller crew, meaning less living quarters. Aside from being a possibly larger risk of hacks it was more of a "Where are we gonna cram the survivors that were already in tight living arrangements if we sacrifice the only warship that can house x amount for a ship that carries half?"

I personally believe it was the only real choice...sucks, but again, survival was priority. Remember, it wasn't about winning fights at this point; it was about keeping as many humans alive and running from a vastly superior force.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This seems to mostly be covered in the existing answers; you can make this a better answer if you can find any evidence of the characters taking these points into consideration.

Answer (score -2):

Galatica wouldn't have been capable of the job.  Trying to replace Pegasus with Galtaica would have lost both ships.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This seems like an opinion, or at least a thesis that requires a proper argument to support.  You could make this a much better answer by explaining *why* the *Galactica* would be unable to cover the retreat of *Pegasus*.